# Can I publish Open Graph Actions from my Facebook app to a user's news feed in addition to their timeline?

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph, feed, facebook-timeline

I have set up Actions for my facebook open graph app and can successfully publish actions to my timeline. This is great.

However I was expecting to be able to also publish these actions to my newsfeed in the same way I can publish a story to the feed. I am using the Javascript API.

I publish the action to the timeline using  -

```
FB.api('/me/MY_APP_NAMESPACE:MY_ACTION?MY_OBJECT=URL', 'post', function(response) {...});
```

I publish a story to the feed using -

```
FB.ui({method:feed, name:SOME_STRING, link:SOME_URL, picture:SOME_IMAGE_URL, caption:SOME_STRING, description:SOME_STRING}, function(response) {...});
```

I would like to be able to publish the action to both the timeline and the news feed. When a user clicks on the action in the timeline it opens that object page and I want the same behavior from the news feed.

Comment: #1 in [Open Graph Checklist](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/checklist/): "A single user action should not trigger multiple timeline stories (e.g. stream.publish story and open graph)."

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you publish an Open Graph action, the action is automatically eligible to appear in the user's Timeline, AND the Ticker and News Feeds of their friends.

You do not need to post anything more to the API, you certainly do not need to make a separate  Feed call.

Comment: I accepted your answer but I'd like to revisit this question - since I have been testing this with some test users (both 'real' profiles and facebook 'test profiles') i have noticed that the actions that I am publishing to a timeline are not always appearing on the news feed. Only once out of about 10 times did the story appear on the news feed of a friend who performed the action. have you encountered this before and can you offer any explanation? many thanks

Comment: News Feed distribution won't be present for every action, the nature of Open Graph publishing is that the individual stories may not be interesting by themselves, but the aggregations ("X of your friends [verbed] [nouns]"), and coincidences ("you and Bob both [verb]ed the same [noun] using [app]") are much more interesting and get better distribution

Answer (score 2):

This question is over a year old, and who knows what's changed since then. But, I was having the same problem this week. Stuff always showed up in the Timeline, but never the News Feed.

I solved it by passing `fb:explicitly_shared=true`

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/guides/explicit-sharing/